# How to get current action(method) name?

Tags: laravel

Laravel 7
I have seen other posts. Answers like this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(Route $route)
    {
        echo $route->getActionName();
    }
}
```

I tried.

```
use Route;

class WorkstationController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        //$xxx = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName();
        $xxx = Route::getRoutes()->match($this->request)->getActionName();
        echo $xxx; exit;
    }
```

But what I got is

```
Closure
```

Only the 7 letters on page. I want, 'index', or 'create', or 'edit'. Why is my result different from others?

Maybe it is because I used this following codes in my route.php ?

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'Payroll', 'as' => 'payroll.', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        
        Route::put('{controller_name}/{controller_method?}', function ($controller_name, $controller_method) {
            $controller = app()->make('\App\Http\Controllers\Hongli\Payroll\\' . ucfirst($controller_name) . 'Controller');
            return $controller->callAction($controller_method, $parameters = []);
        });
        
        Route::post('{controller_name}/{controller_method?}', function ($controller_name, $controller_method) {
            $controller = app()->make('\App\Http\Controllers\Hongli\Payroll\\' . ucfirst($controller_name) . 'Controller');
            return $controller->callAction($controller_method, $parameters = []);
        });

        Route::get('{controller_name}/{controller_method?}', function ($controller_name, $controller_method = 'index') {
            $controller = app()->make('\App\Http\Controllers\Hongli\Payroll\\' . ucfirst($controller_name) . 'Controller');
            return $controller->callAction($controller_method, $parameters = []);
        });
    });
```

If so, how to solve it?

Comment: I don't really understand your question , but if you were looking how to get method name then you can use `__METHOD__`

Comment: It is because you are using closures in your routes. It will only know what action you are using if you use actions instead of closures